# How can an html5 video be muted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm building a page for a client and he would like me to showcase some of his videos on his gallery. Problem is, he does a lot of masonry/construction/concrete work and he just doesn't give a crap about swearing and just sounding like  total dick in his videos. Nonetheless he wants me to put them online.

My question is this: can I use some sort of html5 selector/js/jquery/css/etc to remove the volume control from the video tag? I could just use some other program to remove all the sound completely from the original videos but I was if there's a better, more elegant way.

i already tried something like this:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
myVideo.muted = true;
```

and it worked but it only *started* the video muted. It still left the option to increase volume. Basically i want the users to be able to see the video and have all the controls availablet o them except for the sound. I want the video to start muted and the user to not have any way to increase the sound.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe edit video and get rid of voices? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API in HTML 5 to force the sound to stay off.

You can get rid of the volume controls only by removing the native controls entirely and building your own replacements.

However, that will still let people access the video object through the browser console and use the HTML 5 API to unmute it.

The only way to stop them getting the sound track would be to take it out of the media file before delivering it to the browser.

Comment: Be warned that in Mobile Safari (ipads, iphones), you cannot control the volume of a video at all. So you may want to strip the audio out after all.

Comment: Yeah i actually just read about that earlier today. I finally ended up stripping all the audio from the files. It took me like 4+ hrs because there were like 30 videos and Movie Maker is the sloth equivalent of a video editor. Now... I have to convert them all to .ogv and .webm. This should be another fun journey....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
      <!-- your sources -->
</video>
```

Here you can see a post about HTML 5 video as background: http://www.returngis.net/2014/01/html-5-video-como-background/

Also, you can control this using video.muted property. Something like this:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#movie");     
video.muted = true;
```

Cheers!